# RVIZ Access pose variable of custom msg

Tags: ros, rviz, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have created a custom msg that has a int and a posestamped. Considering that my msg is called customMsg I can do a rostopic echo for customMsg or per example customMsg/Pose and see only the pose variable. How can I achieve the same on rviz? When I do customMsg/Pose on rviz it try to find that exactly topic.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218494/rviz-access-pose-variable-of-custom-msg/) by [metRo_](https://answers.ros.org/users/23114/metro_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2015-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz cannot subscribe to custom message types, unless you write a custom rviz plugin for your message type. Sorry.

rostopic is the only tool that can display only one field from a message; most other tools is ROS do not have that ability.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2